# Plone couldn't set up Zope instance while install Pillow 1.7.8

Tags: installation, virtualenv, plone, enthought, zope

I am trying to install Plone to my Ubuntu 14.04, however the install.sh gives me error:

```
 Installing instance. Getting distribution for 'Pillow==1.7.8'.   
     warning: no previously-included files found matching '.hgignore'   
     warning: no previously-included files found matching '.hgtags'   
     warning: no previously-included files found matching 'BUILDME.bat'  
     warning: no previously-included files found matching   

'make-manifest.py' warning: no previously-included files found   
matching 'SHIP' warning: no previously-included files found matching
'SHIP.bat' warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found 
under directory 'Tests'    _imaging.c:3017:5: warning:
initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    (inquiry) image_length, /*sq_length*/
    ^    _imaging.c:3017:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘image_as_sequence.sq_length’) [enabled by default]   
_imaging.c:3077:5: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    (inquiry) NULL, /*mp_length*/
    ^    _imaging.c:3077:5: warning: (near initialization for ‘pixel_access_as_mapping.mp_length’) [enabled by default]   
_imaging.c: In function ‘_filter’:    _imaging.c:842:8: warning: ‘kernelsize’ may be used uninitialized in this function
[-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
    if (kernelsize != xsize * ysize) {
       ^ libImaging/Quant.c: In function ‘rehash_collide’: libImaging/Quant.c:154:10: warning: cast to pointer from integer of 
different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]    *valp=(void *)((*(int
*)valp)+(*(int *)&newval));
         ^    _imagingft.c:73:31: fatal error: freetype/fterrors.h: No such file or directory  #include <freetype/fterrors.h>
                              ^ compilation terminated. error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 An
error occurred when trying to install Pillow 1.7.8. Look above this 
message for any errors that were output by easy_install. While:     
Installing instance.   Getting distribution for 'Pillow==1.7.8'.   
Error: Couldn't install: Pillow 1.7.8
```

And here is what I did with the Unified installer:

I used `--build-python` option because I am using Enthought Canopy version of Python, which does not have the `Python.h` that Zope needs to in order to build its instance. So I just build up a new python -which honestly I don't know how it works, but I am guessing it is using `virtualenv` to isolate the installation environment, correct me if I am wrong.

```
me@me-N550JV:~/Downloads/Plone-4.3-UnifiedInstaller$ ./install.sh standalone --build-python

Rootless install method chosen. Will install for use by system user me

Detailed installation log being written to /home/me/Downloads/Plone-4.3-UnifiedInstaller/install.log
Installing Plone 4.3 at /home/me/Plone

Skipping libjpeg build
Skipping readline build
Installing Python-2.7.3. This takes a while...
Installing distribute...
Warning: This Python does not have readline support.
It may still be usable for Zope, but interacting directly with Python will be painful.

Python build looks OK.
Unpacking buildout cache to /home/me/Plone/buildout-cache
Copying Plone-docs
Copying buildout skeleton
Fixing up bin/buildout
Building Zope/Plone; this takes a while...
Buildout returned an error code: 1; Aborting.
Buildout failed. Unable to continue

Installation has failed.
See the detailed installation log at /home/me/Downloads/Plone-4.3-UnifiedInstaller/install.log
to determine the cause.
```

Can someone explain how I can fix the issue with Pillow and get Plone installed in my machine? Thanks so much!

Comment: Probably this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105265/install-pil-pillow-via-pip-in-debian-testing-jessie

Comment: Perhaps you could try a later version of Plone - like 4.3.7 ?

Comment: On my Ubuntu Canopy Python.h can be found at "Home/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.5.5.3123.rh5-x86_64/include/python2.7/   Is this file not present in your installation?

Comment: That vaguely looks like Pillow would expect you to have freetype-devel (or freetype-dev? Naming varies between distros) installed when you don't?

Comment: Thanks guys, the problem was solved without using build-python option, instead I contacted with Canopy and moved a missing header file under a  directory that Plone installer is looking at.

Answer (score 1):

install like this 
./install.sh --target=/home/tclap1006/all_folders/unifiedinstallers/Plone --build-python standalone

here --target is path (means at which directory u want to install ur Plone)